# 0211: Keyboard error - external USB keyboard confirmed to work

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, keyboard

I have gotten a message stating that the following error:

`0211: Keyboard error`

The keyboard is also not responding, I have used this keyboard on a different computer without any problems. The computer that it having trouble on is partitioned with both Windows 7 and Crunchbang (debian based).

Prior to this error showing I was having trouble in the linux partition with the keyboard randomly stopping working during use or not working from the linux login screen.

Comment: Did you have the above error when running Linux or Windows?

Comment: It is during the initial boot before GRUB is loaded.